# AWS Python Athena Install Error on pip install jupyter-athena-sql

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-athena

Facing issue on installing **jupyter-athena-sql** . Seems like its because of `jupyter-athena-sql` requires a package from  `pyathena.converter` called `TypeConverter`.

```
!pip install pyathena # Worked
from pyathena.converter import Converter # Worked
!pip install jupyter-athena-sql # **Error**
```

> from .connection import get_connection
> File "/tmp/pip-install-t_sccvpk/jupyter-athena-sql_94bbe189a6af434d96bd640e62b8dfbf/athena/connection.py",
> line 11, in

> ```
>     from pyathena.converter import TypeConverter
> ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeConverter'
> ---------------------------------------- WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/ea/f8dc5177d8048ef1fa84eb6861d758c254c8438d9826dd84a92b26c48d2e/jupyter-athena-sql-0.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=4b45d8fbaa730cdd4ce70e71c445571d80be35769baaabe4394808c7f2b9d36c
> ```
>
> (from https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter-athena-sql/).

Command errored

> out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for
> full command output. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies
> the requirement jupyter-athena-sql (from versions: 0.0.4) ERROR: No
> matching distribution found for jupyter-athena-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
 pip uninstall pyathena
 pip install pyathena==1.2.0
```

See: https://github.com/markfink/jupyter-athena-sql/blob/develop/requirements.txt